From vim to nvim LazyVim - plugins help needed
moving from my vim setup to LazyVim I have troubles to setup some plugins. Most important would be a working plugin for surround like mini-surround, vim-surround (which I am used to) or nvim-surround. Here my tree - the plugins with _out I am unable to load. I did not change any files from LazyVim starting packages.
.config/nvim $ tree
.
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── filter
│   ├── many_perl_text_filters.pl
│  ...
├── init.lua
├── lazy-lock.json
├── lazyvim.json
├── lua
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── autocmds.lua
│   │   ├── keymaps.lua
│   │   ├── lazy.lua
│   │   └── options.lua
│   └── plugins
│       ├── colorscheme_out
│       ├── devicons.lua
│       ├── example.lua
│       ├── gruvbox.lua
│       ├── md-preview_out
│       ├── mini-surround_out
│       ├── mini.nvim_out
│       ├── nord-theme_out
│       ├── nvim-surround_out
│       ├── telekasten_out
│       ├── telescope_out
│       ├── treesitter.lua
│       └── vim-surround_out
├── stylua.toml
└── test.md

What I understood so far: nvim/init.lua calls lua/lazy.lua calls all plugins in folder plugins. Ok my naive questions:
I need a clear colorscheme; I never understood the nerdy dark mode. But I am unable to activate it. For gruvbox plugin I tried many variants. Actually I have:
return {
  -- from https://www.lazyvim.org/plugins/colorscheme
  -- added on 2024-08-11
  -- add gruvbox
  { "ellisonleao/gruvbox.nvim" },
  priority = 1000,
  opts = {
    colorscheme = "gruvbox",
    -- style = "day", -- not working
    -- background = "light", -- not working either
  },
}

or in lua/lazy.lua I tried with vim.o.background = "light" which is working, but disables the colorscheme of gruvbox.
Error activating this plugins/gruvbox.lua config:
Failed to load `plugins.gruvbox`

~/.local/share/nvim/lazy/lazy.nvim/lua/lazy/core/fragments.lua:109: attempt to call method 'find' (a nil value)

# stacktrace:
  - lua/config/lazy.lua:20
  - init.lua:5

Now surround, which is my very question:
To make it not too long, what is in my file plugins/nvim-surround.lua:
return {
  -- new test on 2024-08-14
  -- not working
  "kylechui/nvim-surround",
  version = "*",
  event = "VeryLazy",
  config = function()
    require("nvim-surround").setup({
      -- Configuration here, or leave empty to use defaults
    })
  end,
}

Here no start error. LazyVim says, loaded and "already up to date", but the shortcuts are not working.
I am manly using vim for LaTeX and mixed Markdown-Files, to produce books with pandoc or XeLaTeX
Is there a guide or process to help with this specific migration?

Let's see whether people here can help. If you don't get useful answers within a few days, please flag for mod attention so we can migrate the question to the Unix&Linux site for you.

Welcome to [vi.se]! Your question is asking way too many aspects of the setup, please split it into smaller bits, feel free to post into [vi.se] about specific issues you're facing with the specific part of your setup.

For colorscheme, see https://www.lazyvim.org/plugins/colorscheme as an example, you need priority = 1000 to be inside the first Lua table, so return { { "ellisonleao/gruvbox.nvim", priority = 1000 }, ... }

The opts to select colorscheme = "gruvbox" should be inside a Lua table for "LazyVim/LazyVim" again see example above. The style = "day" applies to the "toyonight" theme which is the default theme/colorscheme in LazyVim, but if you're switching to "gruvbox" that doesn't make any sense anymore and it's not going to work.

Your issue with nvim-surround is probably similar, you probably need a Lua table there, so add another set of curly brackets around it.

As stated though, your question is asking way too many things, "I am manly using vim for LaTeX and mixed Markdown-Files, to produce books with pandoc or XeLaTeX" not even sure what I'm supposed to do with that part. As recommended, ask specific questions about the individual bits that are not working and you can probably get useful help with those.

Thx filbranden for the replies. I am new to lazy vim, so my questions are "too many things" and too vague. The nvim-surround example is an extra file: lua/plugins/nvim-sourround.lua. No need for an extra table. The plugin is loaded, but the commands are not working: ysiw) for example.
